# SAS - custom date format

Tags: import, sas

I'm trying to read in a date field that looks like:

Mar 20 2013 12:00AM

I am using the following user-defined date format and it is not working.

```
proc format;
    picture mydate other='%MON %0d %Y %0H:%0M %p' (datatype=datetime);
run;

data DATASET;
    infile CSVFILE 
    delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
    informat TestDate mydate. ;
    format TestDate mydate. ;
run;
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong with this? This is the first time I've needed to use a custom date format and I'm thinking I am missing something small. I am getting the following error:

```
NOTE: Informat MYDATE was not found or could not be loaded.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe you can create INformats using Picture; only formats.  (INformat = taking a string and converting to a (in this case) date value, format = taking a date value and converting to a string.)

Fortunately, ANYDTDTM. seems to read this in fine.  (I changed to 11AM to make sure the time part was okay.)

```
data test;
input @1 x ANYDTDTM19.;
put x= DATETIME17.;
datalines;
Mar 20 2013 11:00AM
;;;;
run;
```